# Is this where the terms "complementary function" and "particular integral" come from?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the $n$th order explicit ordinary differential equation (ODE)
$$
\frac{\text{d}^nf}{\text{d}t^n}(t) = g\left(t,f(t),f'(t),\dots,f^{(n-1)}(t)\right)
$$
Let us integrate both sides once to get
\begin{align}
\int_{\tau_1}^t \frac{\text{d}^nf}{\text{d}t^n}(\lambda_1) \, \text{d}\lambda_1 &= \int_{\tau_1}^t g\left(\lambda_1,f(\lambda_1),f'(\lambda_1),\dots,f^{(n-1)}(\lambda_1)\right) \, \text{d}\lambda_1 \\
\frac{\text{d}^{(n-1)}f}{\text{d}t^{(n-1)}}(t) - \frac{\text{d}^{(n-1)}f}{\text{d}t^{(n-1)}}(\tau_1) &= \int_{\tau_1}^t g\left(\lambda_1,f(\lambda_1),f'(\lambda_1),\dots,f^{(n-1)}(\lambda_1)\right) \, \text{d}\lambda_1 \\
\frac{\text{d}^{(n-1)}f}{\text{d}t^{(n-1)}}(t) &= \frac{\text{d}^{(n-1)}f}{\text{d}t^{(n-1)}}(\tau_1) + \int_{\tau_1}^t g\left(\lambda_1,f(\lambda_1),f'(\lambda_1),\dots,f^{(n-1)}(\lambda_1)\right) \, \text{d}\lambda_1
\end{align}
where $\tau_1$ is used to specify the antiderivative and $\lambda_1$ is a dummy variable for integration. For clarity, let
$$
\int_{\tau_1}^t g\left(\lambda_1,f(\lambda_1),f'(\lambda_1),\dots,f^{(n-1)}(\lambda_1)\right) \, \text{d}\lambda_1 = G_1(t,\tau_1)
$$
such that
$$
\frac{\text{d}^{(n-1)}f}{\text{d}t^{(n-1)}}(t) = \frac{\text{d}^{(n-1)}f}{\text{d}t^{(n-1)}}(\tau_1) + G_1(t,\tau_1)
$$
If we repeat this integration process once more, we get
\begin{align}
\int_{\tau_2}^t \frac{\text{d}^{(n-1)}f}{\text{d}t^{(n-1)}}(\lambda_2) \, \text{d}\lambda_2 &= \frac{\text{d}^{(n-1)}f}{\text{d}t^{(n-1)}}(\tau_1) \int_{\tau_2}^t \, \text{d}\lambda_2 + \int_{\tau_2}^t G_1(\lambda_2,\tau_1) \, \text{d}\lambda_2 \\
\frac{\text{d}^{(n-2)}f}{\text{d}t^{(n-2)}}(t) - \frac{\text{d}^{(n-2)}f}{\text{d}t^{(n-2)}}(\tau_2) &= \frac{\text{d}^{(n-1)}f}{\text{d}t^{(n-1)}}(\tau_1) \cdot (t - \tau_2) + G_2(t,\tau_1,\tau_2) \\
\frac{\text{d}^{(n-2)}f}{\text{d}t^{(n-2)}}(t) &= \frac{\text{d}^{(n-2)}f}{\text{d}t^{(n-2)}}(\tau_2) + \frac{\text{d}^{(n-1)}f}{\text{d}t^{(n-1)}}(\tau_1) \cdot (t - \tau_2) + G_2(t,\tau_1,\tau_2)
\end{align}
where, as before, $\tau_2$ is used to specify the antiderivative, $\lambda_2$ is a dummy variable for integration, and $G_2(t,\tau_1,\tau_2)$ is defined in a similar way to the definition of $G_1(t,\tau_1)$. For clarity, let
$$
\frac{\text{d}^{(n-2)}f}{\text{d}t^{(n-2)}}(\tau_2) + \frac{\text{d}^{(n-1)}f}{\text{d}t^{(n-1)}}(\tau_1) \cdot (t - \tau_2) = H_2(t,\tau_1,\tau_2)
$$
such that
$$
\frac{\text{d}^{(n-2)}f}{\text{d}t^{(n-2)}}(t) = H_2(t,\tau_1,\tau_2) + G_2(t,\tau_1,\tau_2)
$$
If we repeat this integration process $n-2$ more times, we would get
$$
f(t) = H_n(t,\tau_1,\dots,\tau_n) + G_n(t,\tau_1,\dots,\tau_n)
$$
Given this expression, is it true that $H_n(t,\tau_1,\dots,\tau_n)$ is the *complementary function* and that $G_n(t,\tau_1,\dots,\tau_n)$ is the *particular integral*? That is,
$$
f(t) = \underbrace{H_n(t,\tau_1,\dots,\tau_n)}_{\text{complementary function}} + \underbrace{G_n(t,\tau_1,\dots,\tau_n)}_{\text{particular integral}}
$$

Comment: It turns out that some differential equations can be solved [by quadrature](https://math24.net/equations-solvable-quadratures.html) using, for example, the [Cauchy formula for repeated integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, these names apply only to linear DE and linear systems, due to their relation to general linear algebra and solution theory of systems of linear equations, especially that the solution space is an affine-linear subset parallel to the kernel.

The complementary solution is the solution of the homogeneous variant of the equation.

The or a particular solution is one single solution to the full inhomogeneous equation.

The general solution is the sum of particular and complementary solution. The integration constants or initial condition occur as parameters in the complementary solution.

---

For the calculation you did, an easier approach is to use the Taylor formula with integral reminder term,
$$
f(t)=f(τ)+f'(τ)(t-τ)+...+\frac{f^{(n-1)}(τ)}{(n-1)!}(t-τ)^{n-1}+
\int_τ^t\frac{f^{(n)}(λ)}{(n-1)!}(t-λ)^{n-1}\,dλ
$$
where you can now insert the differential equation with initial conditions to get an equivalent integral equation.

Comment: What if $g(\cdot)$ is a linear function of $t,f(t),f'(t),\dots,f^{(n-1)}(t)$? Would the names for $H_n$ and $G_n$ be correct then?

Comment: No, the Taylor formula that you get via partial integration from the nested integrals does even then not provide this split. Note that the first part is polynomial, which is rarely a solution to a linear DE.

Comment: Ahh I see. In that case, if $g(\cdot)$ is a linear function, would the expression for $f(t)$ that you mentioned then be equivalent to the solution via a sum of a complementary function and a particular integral (even though $H_n$ and $G_n$ do not represent these)? That is, instead of solving the linear ODE via a complementary solution and particular integral, can I instead solve it via the Taylor formula approach?

Comment: No, a true solution has to resolve the recursion that the unknown function occurs on both sides (in different stages of differentiation or integration). The integral equation used as fixed-point equation is a theoretical device, in that the iteration map maps continuous functions to $C^n$ functions. These in turn are a small thin set inside the continuous functions (see Arzela-Ascoli), and this squeezing when applying the fixed-point iteration provides the background for the successful application of diverse fixed-point theorems, most commonly Banach.

Comment: Not sure I follow. In the equation in your answer, $$f(t)=f(τ)+f'(τ)(t-τ)+...+\frac{f^{(n-1)}(τ)}{(n-1)!}(t-τ)^{n-1}+\int_τ^t\frac{f^{(n)}(λ)}{(n-1)!}(t-λ)^{n-1}\,dλ$$ $f(t)$ is on the LHS, while $f(\tau),f'(\tau),...,f^{(n-1)}(\tau)$ are assumed to be given as initial conditions on the RHS. So, I am not sure where an unknown function occurs on the RHS of this equation.

Comment: $f^{(n)}$ gets replaced with the $g$ expression. And this is exactly the recursion, you can not solve explicitly for $f(t)$, this value depends on values and derivatives at points at all points $λ\in]τ,t[$.